# Why doesnt this work? (html/javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

I want this to just check if it is correct or not, I am not to smart about HTML so I really would like if someone could explain like im a little kid so I can understand.
Here is the code:

```html
<input type="text" id="user" value="">
<input type="password" id="pass" value="">
<button type="button" id="btn" onclick="func()">Login</button>
<h1 id="txt"></h1>
<script>
  var userstate = "false";
  var passstate = "false";

  function func() {
    var utxt = document.getElementById("user").value;
    var ptxt = document.getElementById("pass").value;
    if (utxt == "david")
      userstate = "true";
    if (ptxt == "lol123")
      passstate = "true";
    if (userstate == "true" && passstate == "true")
      var txt = "Login succesfully";
    else
      var txt = "Login not succesfull";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Instead of having true in strings, remove the quotation marks to make them boolean values. Then you can check `if (userstate && passstate)`

Comment: It works. Try adding `console.log(txt)` and/or `document.getElementbyId("txt")=txt` before the last `}` - and also remove the quotes from the false and true - then you can do `if (userstate && passstate)`

Comment: `Why doesn't this work?` - What do you expect to happen and what is happening instead? - Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more details.

Comment: `document.getElementById("txt").textContent = txt;` try adding this at the function closing.

Comment: Also, this may well work as you intend but the Javascript variable txt isn't used for anything.

Comment: You shold really look into JavaScript's JSLint: http://www.jslint.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues

1. remove the quotes from false and true or use a direct assignment and a ternary like I do below
2. put the initialisation of the states INSIDE the function, otherwise I can change the names after entering ok names.
3. output the txt variable
4. NEVER have password testing in client JS - but I guess you are just playing

```html
<input type="text" id="user" value="">
<input type="password" id="pass" value="">
<button type="button" id="btn" onclick="func()">Login</button>
<h1 id="txt"></h1>
<script>
  function func() {
    var utxt = document.getElementById("user").value;
    var ptxt = document.getElementById("pass").value;
    var userstate = utxt == "david";
    var passstate = ptxt == "lol123";
    document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML=(userstate && passstate)?"Login successful": "Login not successful";
  }
</script>
```

Using profiles **AGAIN**: Do NOT use client based password validations except to keep your kid sister from entering a page.

```html
<input type="text" id="user" value="">
<input type="password" id="pass" value="">
<button type="button" id="btn" onclick="func()">Login</button>
<h1 id="txt"></h1>
<script>
  var profiles={ "david":"lol123", "fred":"xdf456"};
  function func() {
    var utxt = document.getElementById("user").value;
    var ptxt = document.getElementById("pass").value;
    var success= profiles[utxt] && profiles[utxt]==ptxt; // the name exists and matches the password
    document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML=(success)?"Login successful": "Login not successful";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You want to have sets of you userids and passwords? `var success= (profiles[utxt] && profiles[utxt]==ptxt) ...` using `var profiles={ "david":"lol123", "fred":"xdf456"}`

Comment: Where do I put them?

Comment: See second example

Comment: Thank you really much, and I wont use this as any serius, I am just trying around :D

Answer (score 2):

You should put your login message in the div with the id txt using:

```
document.getElementById('txt').innerHtml = "the text";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" id="user" value="">
<input type="password" id="pass" value="">
<button type="button" id="btn" onclick="func()">Login</button>
<h1 id="txt"></h1>
<script>
var userstate="false";
var passstate="false";
function func()
{
  var utxt = document.getElementById("user").value;
  var ptxt = document.getElementById("pass").value;
  if (utxt == "david")
    userstate = "true";
  if (ptxt == "lol123")
    passstate = "true";
  if (userstate == "true" && passstate == "true")
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = "Login succesfully";
  else
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =  "Login not succesfull";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Also**

Boolean (true | false) do not require quotes:

You can simply use:

```
userstate = true;
```

Or

```
userstate = fale;
```

and check them as:

```
if(userstate == false){}
```

Comment: or just `if (userstate)`